# Psychological Diagnostic Test

Tags: abnormal-psychology, methodology, psychology, clinical-psychology, personality-disorder

Can a person sway the results of their Psychiatric diagnosis test? Say a person has a mental illness that is more serious that they want to accept, if they know enough about Psychology, can they gear their answers toward a different diagnosis that is more acceptable to them and society?

When looking into this question many articles are listed about lie detector tests. https://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/detecting-lies-in-the-brain/

Some articles deal with how an individual might be able to detect another person's deception and the kinds of deception exhibited. https://pro.psychcentral.com/exhausted-woman/2017/03/the-levels-of-deceptive-people/

other articles deal with self-deception and possible reasons why. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6353154/

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.01718/full.

I would like to know if a professional evaluation of an patient can be manipulated to achieve the results that patient wants while being deceptive concerning the more accurate diagnosis. For example someone with a serious personality disorder being diagnosis with a more socially acceptable illness, such as ADHD or anxiety disorder because of the deceptive interaction of the patient during the evaluation? Is there a way for a professional to determine what is the true diagnosis vs the diagnosis the patient consciously wants to be evaluated as suffering from?

The reason's why this patient might want to be diagnosed with a inaccurate illness may be many, as of now I am not interested in that unless it affects my original question.